# A less complex solution maybe

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-x+1=0$, then $a^{2009}+b^{2009}$ is

One way to solve this is to multiply the equation by $x+1$ and obtain the cubic $x^3+1=0$ and then the roots will be $-1$, $-w$, $-w^{2}$ where $w$ is the cube root of unity, so $a$ and $b$ will be equal to $-w$, and $-w^{2}$.

I wanted to solve this using a method which did not involve complex numbers but couldn't think of any, can anybody please help me.

Comment: This is an odd request: you should accept complex numbers the moment you read "if $a$, $b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-x+1=0$" without arguing that $x^2-x+1>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ (and therefore no such $a$, $b$ exist in $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Your two roots are z = 1/2(1 +- sqrt(3)i).    If you express a complex number z = (x + yi) in polar coordinates (R,theta), where R= length of z (sqrt(x*x + y*y)) and theta = arctan(y/x), then z^A = (R^A, A*theta).  In other words, the length R is raised to the power A, and the angle is MULTIPLIED by the power A.  For your problem, R=1, so R to any power is also 1.  So to find z^2009, you just need to compute the new angle, theta, which is 2009 * pi/3 (for the first root) and 2009 * (-pi/3) for the second.  Try it!

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2 - x + 1 = 0 \implies x^3 - x^2 + x = 0$$

But $$x^2 - x = -1$$
(using the quadaratic again)

Thus $$x^3 = -1$$

So $a^3 = -1$ and $b^3 = -1$.

Thus $$a^{2009} + b^{2009} = a^{3 \cdot 669} a^2 + b^{3 \cdot 669} b^2 = -a^2 - b^2 = 2ab - (a + b)^2 $$

($2007 = 3\cdot669$)

But $a+b = 1$ (sum of roots of quadratic)

and $ab = 1$ (product of roots of quadratic)

Thus the answer is $$1$$

Answer (score 2):

Take root $a$ for example and note that $\,a^2-a+1=0\,$ since it's a root of the equation. Then:

$$a^2 = a-1 \tag{1}$$

$$a^2 - a = -1 \tag{2}$$

Multiply $(1)$ by $\,a \ne 0\,$ and use $(2)\,$ to get:

$$
a^3 = a^2-a = -1
$$

It follows that $a^{2009}=\left(a^3\right)^{669} \cdot a^2=(-1)^{669} \cdot a^2=-a^2\,$. Same goes for b, so the sum is:

$$-a^2-b^2=-a+1-b+1=-(a+b)+2=1$$

Comment: $a \ne 0$ is irrelevant and having that will only confuse the students.

Comment: @Aryabhata $a \ne 0$ is what makes the multiplication a two-way equivalence, rather than a one-way implication. You are right of course that it's irrelevant *here*, but I still think it's good practice to develop the habit of considering that, for *other* cases where it may in fact matter.

Comment: I think it is a good practice to not waste brain cells when not needed :-P

Answer (score 0):

You can't choose the roots of a polynomial . There may be no roots in the real numbers.  if you look at the equation you can get $$x^2-x=-1 \implies (x-1)x=-1 \implies \text {x is negative or x-1 is negative}$$ if x is negative so is x-1 so that's out, as a negative times a negative is a positive. x-1 being negative shows that x is in the half open interval from 0 to 1, x=0 implies 0=-1  , which is false. x=1 causes both x and x-1 to be non-negative (slightly different from positive, and x=1 wouldn't be in the half open interval). if x is rational then we have that the absolute values of x and x-1 are flipped fractions ( aka $x={a\over b}, x-1 = -{b\over a}$). otherwise the solutions would have to be irrational ( which then begs the question can two irrational numbers multiplied together equal a rational). if this last ditch effort fails ( admittedly I don't know) then there would be no solutions in the reals ( the set union of the rationals and irrationals)

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{2009}+b^{2009}=a^2(a^3)^{669}+b^2(b^3)^{669}=-(a^2+b^2)=-((a+b)^2-2ab)=-(1-2)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $k_n = a^n+b^n$ for integer $n$. Consider the proposition

> $$k_n = a^n + b^n = 2\cos\frac{2\pi n}6$$

For $n = 0$, $a^0 + b^0 = 2 = 2\cos 0$.

For $n = 1$, $a + b = 1 = 2\cos \frac{2\pi}6$.

Assume the proposition is true for $m-1$ and $m$, where $m\ge 1$ is an integer,

$$k_i = a^i + b^i = 2\cos \frac{2\pi i}6,\quad i = m-1, m$$

For $n = m + 1$,

$$\begin{align*}
a^{m+1} + b^{m+1} &= a(a^m+b^m) + b(a^m+b^m) - ab^m - a^mb\\
&= (a+b)(a^m+b^m) - ab(a^{m-1}+b^{m-1})\\
&= k_m - k_{m-1}\\
&= 2\cos\frac{2\pi m}6 - 2\cos\frac{2\pi(m-1)}6\\
&= 2\cdot(-2)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}\cdot\frac{2m-1}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&= -2\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{6}\left(m -\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\\
&= 2\cos\left[\frac {2\pi}6\left(m -\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{2\pi}{4}\right]\\
&= 2\cos\left[\frac {2\pi}6\left(m -\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{2\pi}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\right]\\
&= 2\cos\frac {2\pi(m+1)}6
\end{align*}$$

So the proposition is true by induction for non-negative integers $n$, and

$$a^{2009}+b^{2009} = 2\cos\frac{2\pi\cdot2009}6 = 2\cos\frac{2\pi\cdot5}6 = 1$$